# Resizing a specific TinyMCE editor added by JS

Tags: javascript, resize, tinymce

I am adding/replacing two textareas with TinyMCE via two different javascript clicks/calls. They have different IDs and are being added correctly by the 'execCommand' call:

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceAddControl',true,'comment1');
```

However, I am having trouble resizing the objects when there are more than one on screen. If there is just one I am able to successfully call 'resizeTo' using the 'activeEditor' to resize the object, like this:

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceAddControl',true,'comment1');
var ed = tinymce.activeEditor;
ed.theme.resizeTo(400, 200);
```

But when there is more than one editor, I cannot use 'activeEditor' and I don't know how to select a specific editor to resize. I have tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
var edd = tinymce.get('comment2');
edd.theme.resizeTo(350,306);
```

Any help/suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have to working tinymce editors with textareas as source elements you have given each of those testareas a unique id. This id will help you to get the correct editor instance.

Use

```
var editor = tinymce.get('your_textarea_id');
```

to get the correct editor. That's all.

Comment: I believe my problem was that I was trying to resize it to a size (width in particular) that was lower than the min allowed width (because of the toolbars perhaps?). So I wasn't seeing it resize and believed it wasn't working. Thanks for the reply!